# how to perevent polling duplicated data from mysql database

Tags: mysql, jpa, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have a big amount of data in a mysql database. I want to poll data from database and push them in a activemq in camel. the connection between database and queue will be lost every 15 minutes. some of the messages are lost during connection interruption. I need to know which messages are lost to poll them again from database. the messages should not be send more that one time. and this should be done without any changes in database schema.(i can not add any Boolean status field to my database).

any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you need to have some unique identifier in the data you pull from the source database. Maybe it is whatever has already been defined as the primary key. Or, maybe the table has some timestamp field. Or, maybe some combination of fields will be unique.

Once you identify that, when you are putting the data into the target, reject any key that is already in the target. You could use Camel's "idempotency" features, but if you are able to check for the key in the target database, you probably won't need anything else.

If you have to make the decision about what to **send**, but do not have access to your remote database from App #1, you'll need to keep a record on the other side of the firewall.

You would need to do this, even if the connection did not break every 15 minutes...because you could have failures for other reasons.

If you can have an Idempotency database for App#1, another approach could be to transfer data from the local database to some other local table, and read from this. Then you poll this other table, and delete whenever the send is successful.
Example:

It looks like you're using MySql. If both databases are on MySql, you could look into [MySql data-replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html), rather than using your own app, with Camel.